# How can I check exception handling in JUnit?

Tags: java

that if an error occurs, an exceptional situation will actually occur.
How to make a test so that it checks that an exception really occurs?

```
 private String getTemplate(String templateName) {
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("templates/" 
                   + templateName).getFile()
        );
        StringBuilder templateString = new StringBuilder();

        char[] symbol = new char[256];
        int readBytes;
        while((readBytes = reader.read(symbol)) > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++)
                templateString.append(symbol[i]);

        return templateString.toString();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "{'detail': 'internal server error: page not found'}";
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "{'detail': 'internal server error: page cannot be read'}";
    }
}
```

Comment: you return a `String`, even if an Exception is thrown - assert on that

Comment: @Eugene the question is: how to make sure the NPE is thrown

Comment: @Eugene so: how would you write the test? you're aware it could not be tested unless you can guarantee the NPE to be thrown?

Comment: @Stultuske do you mean that the OP wants to simulate that Exception somehow?

Comment: that's what I think he's trying to do, yes, but I don't see any of his own services he calls he could mock to make it happen

Comment: @Stultuske you could move the code that generates the `reader` into a separate method and create a `Spy`

Comment: indeed a possibility. Not sure whether he's able to change the original code, or is looking for a way to test it without changing the code

Comment: Where is your JUnit code?

Answer (score 2):

Basically your problem is that you wrote **hard to test** code:

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("templates/" 
               + templateName).getFile()
```

This call to new basically translates to: if at all, you need PowerMock(ito) or JMockit to gain control over your production code.

What you could do instead: **pass** a FileReader object to that method, so that it just calls method on that object. And then you can use Mockito to provide a *mocked* FileReader to that code. By doing so, you can then control what happens when you test your production code.

And then you could do something like:

```
@Test
public void testNPE() {
  Mockito.when(mockedFileReader.read(ArgumentsMatcher.any())).thenThrow(new NullPointerException("haha"));
  String result = objectUnderTest.callAPublicMethodThatCallsTheMethodUnderTest(foo);

  assertThat(result, is("{'detail': 'internal server error: page not found'}");
  }
```

The above instructs that mocked file reader to throw a NPE when its read() method is called. Then you would expect your production code to return that string.

As you can see, there are a lot of things you have to "fill":

- you can't call private methods, so obviously, you would have to call a public entry point to your class under test
- it only works when that string coming out of the private method somehow shows up in the response of that public method
- and, as said: *somehow* that mocked file reader needs to get *into* that *objectUnderTest*

Finally: it is a very bad idea to catch NPE, and assume that this means "page not found". A null pointer is just that: a reference to null. If at all, your code should be checking some condition to come to the conclusion "page not found". A NPE can happen for many reasons. There could be a code bug, and you go and tell the customer "page not found"?!

Thus the real answer is a different one: you should step back and do quite a bit of research how you do proper unit testing, maybe using a framework like Mockito. And then you learn how to write code that can be **easily** tested. As said: the code you wrote is basically untestable. You better fix that, instead of hoping that some magic framework helps you working around that inherent problem of your code base.